# jsonPath Expression for json and json of json parameter using NIFI expression Langauge

Tags: json, apache-nifi, json-path-expression

I have json like below,

```
{
    "name1" : "Aks",
    "address1": {
      "area" : "area1",
      "location1": "loc1"

    },
    "phonenum": "1445452"
}
```

I need to retrieve all keys and from address1 only location1 parameter.

I tried,
$.*, $.['address1'].location1 
in JsonPath Expression, but didn't succeed, any hint on this ?

Comment: please explain better.. Do you need to extract `name1`, `phonenum`, and `address1.location1` into to their own attributes?

Comment: yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

@aksy91 you need to use the EvaluateJsonPath Processor for the mapping:

```
name1: $.name1

location1: $.address1.location1

phonenum: $.phonenum
```

Be sure to set the first value to flowfile-attribute.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html

Comment: Yes, Worked! Thank you,
One more clarification needed, Can insert this flow-file attributes to local db table using PutDatabaseRecord Prcessor..?
My findings,
ExecuteSQL-->ConvertAvroToJson-->EvaluateJson-->PutDatabaseRecord.
But In PutDatabaseRecord -- > selected JSONTreeRecord as RecordReader and AvroSchemaRegistry as its SchemaAccessStrategy. 
I have oracle DB, I am using 'username' as the 'schema.name', it is failing to insert with error 
failed to process standardflowfilerecord nifi putdatabaserecord..
Please provide any suggestions on this..

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you need to do is to add three new dynamic attributes:

`name1`: `$.name1`

`location1`: `$.address1.location1`

`phonenum`: `$.phonenum`
[image]

[image]

Comment: In same jsonPath Expression ? Any delimiter should be used in the expression Path ?

example : $.name1,$.address1.location1,$.phonenum

Comment: just enter it as is, `attribute_name`: `attribute_value` . Of course, `Destination` should be set to `flowfile-attribute` too. Please tell me if it works for you

Comment: Used as is you mentioned, but no luck.. Where I am going wrong, unable to understand

Comment: please add to your question the full details with screen shots included of what you've tried to perform, I'll add screenshots of what's I've done as well

Comment: I have structure like this, ExecuteSQL --> ConverAvroToJson --> UpdateAttribute --> SplitJson
So in SplitJson I am giving jsonPath Expression like below
name1: $.name1
location1: $.address1.location1
phonenum: $.phonenum

I am doing it correct ?